# How to connect a 2 cell LiPo batter to Arduino Motor Shield?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to connect a 2 cell 7.4 volt LiPo battery into my motor shield. I am a beginner at robotics so I am not sure if I just connect the battery, via a connector of some sort, into the motor shield itself or do I use some 22 AWG wire and connect it via that way. Sorry if that sounds confusing.

Comment: 22 AWG might be a little thin for some wire IMO; for power lines it's usually best to get something thicker, of course something really big would have too much resistance: that's why some power lines have more than 2 cables. (In the US, anyway)

Comment: You might want to check [this about arduino overheating](http://australianrobotics.com.au/news/fuelling-your-arduino-why-you-should-use-an-external-power-breakout).

Answer (score 2):

From the Motor Shield page,

> External (non-USB) power can come either from an AC-to-DC adapter
>   (wall-wart) or battery. The adapter can be connected by plugging a
>   2.1mm center-positive plug into the Arduino's board power jack on which the motor shield is mounted or by **connecting the wires that lead
>   the power supply to the Vin and GND screw terminals, taking care to
>   respect the polarities.**

So they provide the screw terminals for a battery, you should be able to insert two wires from your battery/pack into the terminals. If your battery has a connector on it, you'll need to either cut it off or find an adapter.

**Be extra careful:** if you have exposed leads from your battery and they touch, it'll get extremely hot and possibly catch fire.

Comment: Do I need a separate 5V battery to power arduino board, and my 7.4V battery for motor shield? Can I use one for both?

Answer (score 1):

it is up to you.
Welded cable is better, but you will probably need a connector, so you should take care to use low-ipendance one that can hadle your current need, like `bullet connector` used by RC toys.

Also the battery should have a `discarge current` higher that the maximum current used by the engine: normaly this can be calculated by the discarge factor (labeled as 'C' on the hobbyst battery) multiplied by the capacity in Ah o the battery. Pay attention to this as this can damage the battery and alco cause lipo-fire, witch cannot pulled off with just water, you need an extinguer. (this is what happen when you short-circuit the + and -)